# Unable to find element by any means

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm kinda of a newbie in Selenium, started learning it for my job some time ago. Right now I'm working with a code that will open the browser, enter the specified website, put the products ID in the search box, search, and them open it. Once it opens the product, it needs to extract its name and price and write it in a CSV file. I'm kinda struggling with it a bit.
The main problem right now is that Selenium is unable to open the product after searching it. I've tried by ID, name and class and it still didn't work.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.madeiramadeira.com.br/")
assert "Madeira" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("input-autocomplete")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("525119")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
product_link = driver.find_element_by_id('variant-url').click()
```

The error I get is usually this:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="variant-url"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple elements with the `id="variant-url"`, So you could use the index to click on the desired element, Also you need to handle I think the cookie pop-Up. Check the below code, hope it will help

```
#Disable the notifications window which is displayed on the page
option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"Driver_Path",chrome_options=option)
driver.get("https://www.madeiramadeira.com.br/")
assert "Madeira" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("input-autocomplete")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("525119")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#Clicked on the cookie popup button
accept= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='lgpd-button-agree']")
accept.click()
```

OR with `explicitWait`

```
accept=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='lgpd-button-agree']")))
accept.click()

#Here uses the XPath with the index like [1][2] to click on the specific element
product_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//a[@id='variant-url'])[1])")
product_link.click()
```

OR with `explicitWait`

```
product_link=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"((//a[@id='variant-url'])[1])")))
product_link.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error all the time when starting. The problem is that there are probably multiple elements with the same ID "variant-url". There are two ways you can fix this

1. By using "driver.find_elementS_by_id"

`product_links = driver.find_elements_by_id('variant-url')`

`product_links[2].click()`

This will create an index off all the elements with id 'variant-url' then click the index of 2. This works but it is annoying to find the correct index of the button you want to click and also takes a long time if there are many elements with the same ID.

2. By using Xpaths or CSS selectors

This way is a lot easier as each element has a specific Xpath of Selector. It will look like this.

`product_link = driver.get_element_by_xpath("XPATH GOES HERE").click()`

To get an Xpath or selector 1. go into developer mode on your browser by inspecting the element 2. right click the element in the F12 menu 3. hover over copy 4. move to copy Xpath and click on it.

[image: Right Cliked on button element then went down to copy then to xpath (selector is 3 above xpath]

Hope this helps you :D